# How to draw a line between 2 different area charts for same category (x axis) in highcharts?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have 2 area charts plotted, of which one is  drag-gable, when the chart is dragged and on click of button, it should draw line between two points (connecting the two) in the same category.  Is this possible?

Here's the jsFiddle: jsfiddle.net/AyUbx/3118/

It has two area charts.
Image is also attached which explains the requirement.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITGuj.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `chart.renderer` to render that path, for example:

```
var left = chart.plotLeft,
    top = chart.plotTop;

  if(!chart.currentPoint) {
    chart.currentPoint = 0;
  } 

  if (!chart.myPath) {
    chart.myPath = chart.renderer.path(['M', 0, 0]).attr({
      stroke: 'red',
      'stroke-width': 1
    }).add();
  }

  chart.myPath.attr({
    d: [
      'M',
      chart.series[0].data[chart.currentPoint].plotX + left,
      chart.series[0].data[chart.currentPoint].plotY + top,
      'L',
      chart.series[1].data[chart.currentPoint].plotX + left,
      chart.series[1].data[chart.currentPoint].plotY + top
    ]
  });
```

And live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hkju4mzk/

Comment: I have tried your solution, it worked very nicely. Thanks a lot